# How can I alter this CSS so that it only applies to a certain div?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body
{
    line-height: 1;
}
ol,ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote,q
{
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after
{
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
:focus
{
    outline: 0;
}
ins
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
del
{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

How can I change it so that it applies only to the div called `header` and the elements within?

Comment: That's a batch of reset styles, designed to normalise styles between browsers. Do you mean that you want to 'reset' the styles of everything inside `div#header`, but leave everything else alone? If that's right, the styles you have here will be overkill...

Comment: Please go back and edit your question to properly format the code. It's terribly formatted now, and it's such a mess my attempt to straighten it out was too time-consuming. If you want help, you should at least put forth the effort to make it legible and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header html, #header body, #header div, #header span, #header applet, #header object, #header iframe ... etc etc.
```

As beejamin has pointed out you need to thin down your CSS it is overkill for a div which will not have an html tag, or body tag etc, etc

--------- update

```
 #header, #header div, #header span, #header applet, #header object, #header iframe, #header h1, #header h2, #header h3, #header h4, #header h5, #header h6, #header p, #header blockquote, #header pre, #header a, #header abbr, #header acronym, #header address, #header big, #header cite, #header code, #header del, #header dfn, #header em, #header font, #header img, #header ins, #header kbd, #header q, #header s, #header samp, #header small, #header strike, #header strong, #header sub, #header sup, #header tt, #header var, #header b, #header u, #header i, #header center, #header dl, #header dt, #header dd, #header ol, #header ul, #header li, #header fieldset, #header form, #header label, #header legend, #header table, #header caption, #header tbody, #header tfoot, #header thead, #header tr, #header th #header , #header td
{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#header 
{
    line-height: 1;
}
#header ol,#header ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
#header blockquote,#header q
{
    quotes: none;
}
#header blockquote:before,#header blockquote:after,#header q:before,#header q:after
{
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
#header:focus
{
    outline: 0;
}
#header ins
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header del
{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
#header table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Because of the amount of CSS changes an easier solution may be to place the header in a separate html and place it onto the page using a object or iframe.

On a much smaller scale I am using this style of selectors on my site's drop down menu bar - they work with IE6.

Although alternative child selectors http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ may also work with IE6?

```
#header > div ...
    {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        outline: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
```

would only go one level deep in your id=header div.